# Why does a desktop launcher does not start my app, while the .desktop file is working?

Tags: launcher, .desktop, zotero

I installed a package (Zotero) in `/opt` and I am able to run it perfectly using command line.

The package comes with a `.desktop` file, so I added it to `/usr/share/applications` and gave it the executable permission. When I double-click on the `.desktop` file, the software is starting normally. The corresponding icon appears in the desktop launcher. However, when I click on the icon in the desktop launcher, nothing is happening. I have no idea why.

Here is the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Zotero
Exec=/opt/zotero/zotero
Icon=/opt/zotero/chrome/icons/default/default256.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Office;
MimeType=text/plain
```

Would anyone know why the launcher does not launch my app?

Comment: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/77220/ubuntu-18-04-adding-a-launcher-for-zotero may be helpful.

Comment: I deleted the MimeType line and nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: I also looked at the zotero forum discussion, but I have the feeling that I did everything correctly. The desktop file seems to work fine with a double click, so there is no obvious path problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer: there were two .desktop files, a correct one in /usr/share/applications and an incorrect one in /home/.local/share/applications (path was not correct). Replacing the incorrect one by the correct one solved the issue.

I probably got mixed up in the installation and then forgot the incorrect .desktop file. It prevented me to launch the app from the launcher or the Favorites, even when I pinned it in the Favorites after launching it correctly with the command line.

Thank you for all who helped!